# Multiple-definition error for classes in Eclipse

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse

I have a "multiple definition" error in Eclipse when trying to include a file called sniffer.h.

sniffer.h:

```
#ifndef SNIFFER_H_
#define SNIFFER_H_
#include "sys/types.h"
#include "sys/socket.h"
#include "netinet/in.h"
#include "netdb.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <queue>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/timeb.h>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <math.h>
#include <syslog.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <asm-generic/errno-base.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
//Syslog libraries.
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;


string gconfigfilename = "config";          //Holds the config file name, dynamic     because of the add_interface option.
int pipehandler;                            //pipe handler for     the pipe that the gulp writes to
string pipeFullName;                        //absolute path for the pipe that the gulp writes to
FILE* pipe_fd;
```

And it has the statements of all the functions in sniffer.cpp:

```
#include "../h/sniffer.h"

     void OpenPipeRead(/*string sinterface*/)
{
    int ret_val;
    pipeFullName = "";
    pipeFullName.append(mconfig[C_PIPEPATH]);
    //Its not empty only when there is argument for parallal telepath_sniff instances.
    pipeFullName.append(mconfig[C_PIPENAME]);
    //if(strcmp(sinterface.c_str(), "") != 0)
    //  lpipename.append("_" + sinterface);     
    printf("Try to open Pipe for reading\n");
    syslog(LOG_INFO, "Try to open Pipe for reading\n"); 
    /* Create the named - pipe */
    ret_val = mkfifo(pipeFullName.c_str(), 0666);
    if ((ret_val == -1) && (errno != EEXIST)) {
        perror("Error creating the pipe");
        syslog(LOG_ERR, "Error creating the pipe");         
        exit(1);
    }       
    if((pipehandler = open(pipeFullName.c_str(), O_RDWR)) < 1)      /* Open the pipe for reading and writing , in append mode */
    {
       perror("Failed to open pipe");
       syslog(LOG_ERR, "Failed to open pipe");
       exit(1);
    }
    printf("Pipe opened.\n");
    syslog(LOG_INFO, "Pipe opened.\n");
}
```

However in the first function it says that `pipeFullName` has multiple definitions again.

I only included it once and the string is defined in sniffer.h.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### You should not include `.cpp` file!!!

In doing so you end up violating the **[One definition Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule)**.

The usual way is to place **declarations** in header files and **definitions** in cpp files.
You can declare something as many times as you want but define it only once.

So you should be including header files only. if you include a cpp file, a copy of definition of symbols in the cpp file get added to every translation unit where you include the header file thus violating the ODR.

Comment: Ok I moved all the vars to the corresponding h file and included it in the cpp file I also declared all the functions as required in the h file...and included the h file in the cpp file yet now it says that some of the vars are "multiple defined" :-\

Comment: @user1432779: Did you declare some variables in the header file? I am sure you did. You shouldn't do that.If you want to share variable across multiple files check how to use the keyword `extern`.

Comment: Thanks it worked...I haven't worked with c++ for a while..up on running